# take out spaces when parsing html to textview

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse an html page while trying to take out everything that is within <> so that all the tags are and only the content is left with this line of code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");
```

But what I didn't intent for it to happen is for the replaced text is simply replaced by white space instead of being taken out completely; it still takes up space so I would have unwanted white spaces in my textview. So if I had the following lines on html:

```
hi
<somethingsomething>
<something>
stuff
```

it becomes this after my line of code:

```
hi


stuff
```

But I want to make it parsed into something like this:

```
hi
stuff
```

How should I go about doing that?

Comment: This should help

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123385/remove-all-empty-lines