# Java - Remove html tags and free lines

Tags: java, string, split

Before asking, I tried to find the solution from other threads but without success. Now:
I need to remove tags from a html code. I did that using:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
```

and this worked. But now I have a problem:
in free lines it doesn't work because it take me the space.
ex:
input:

```
< tag="/name/'> < tag bla="itemprop">

< tag="/name/'>TEST< tag bla="itemprop">
```

I want as ouput only: TEST and not

```
(free space)


TEST
```

How can I remove all the blank lines?

Let me clarify my qestion.
Im writing piece of a HTML code on a text file.

I have this output:

```
Brian, Klein
Phil, Churchward
    (free space)
Nigel, Simpkiss
Richard, Heeley
James, Bryce
Andrew, Fettis
Owen, Trevor
    (free space)
Konrad, Begg
Scott, Weintrob
Ben, Duncan
Chris, Richards
Kit, Lynch, Robinson
Southan, Morris
    (free space)
```

How can I remove the spaces between the two "//"?

I used

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
```

But if I have `" < tag="/name/'> < tag bla="itemprop"> "` It takes me the space too!

Comment: I've heard that regex is just the tool for html parsing :) :)

Comment: The same way you used to removed the tags ? `str = str.replaceAll(" ", "").trim();`

Comment: Missing some clarity in the question? are you SIMPLY asking how to remove all blank lines in a file?

Comment: I tried, but there are some spaces that i need.
That if I have TEST ONE, I dont want to get TESTONE.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123385/remove-all-empty-lines

Comment: @user3704449 Yeah that would require a little more work than this, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. On the other hand are you sure this is the way you should be handling XML or HTML code in java ?

Comment: @Autar Please, check my edited question, Im trying to explain my problem as clear as I can. Sorry!

Comment: @user3704449 Are `/` in the output you added new lines ?

Comment: Yes, Here is part of the code:
str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
str = str.replaceAll(" ", ", ");
out.write(String.valueOf(str + "/"));

Comment: I tried with 
if (str != null) { condition, but nothing.

Comment: Ok man! I solved. Tried if str.lengt>0 and it worked. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove blank lines from your String then use:

```
str.replaceAll("\n", "")
```

After removing tags. Hope this helps.

Comment: This would also put all items on the same line if there are several. I'm not sure it's the desired behavior ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use EspaceUtils, then you can escape for html, newlines, java etc.
[Here you go](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

try with `replaceAll("\\n{2,}", "\\n(free space)\\n")`
it doesn't show how many free lines in a row matched