# CSV reader picking up blank lines

Tags: java, csv

I have a program that reads in a `CSV` file and stores the first and last lines as a `JSONObject`. My current implementation is skipping over the last line and reading in a `null` value as the data object.

What's the correct way to create/save a CSV file as to eliminate any white space or null values?

**CSV**

```
   TIME_STAMP,TOTAL,APPLES,ORANGES,PEARS,GRAPES,TANGERINES,PINEAPPLES,CARROTS,UNKNOWN 
    7/1/2015 4:00,19474,1736,275,8366,5352,3003,393,349,
```

**Code**

```
String firstLine = "";
String lastLine = "";

int count = 0;
if(reader != null){
    String aux = "";
    String lastLineMinusOne = "";
    while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(count == 0)firstLine = aux;
            lastLineMinusOne = lastLine;
            lastLine = aux;
            count ++;
        }
        logger.info("Count = " + count);             
        String[] columns = firstLine.split(",");
        String[] data = lastLine.split(",");
        logger.info(firstLine);
        logger.info(lastLine);
```

**Log**

```
    2015-09-28 13:41:42,370 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO  com.ChartData - Count = 3
    2015-09-28 13:23:27,745 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-3] INFO  com.ChartData - TIME_STAMP,TOTAL,APPLES,ORANGES,PEARS,GRAPES,TANGERINES,PINEAPPLES,CARROTS,UNKNOWN
    2015-09-28 13:23:27,745 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-3] INFO  com.ChartData -
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at com.ChartData.getCSV(ChartData.java:75)
```

Line 75 -> `jObject.put("val", data[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. parse line when readed as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123385/remove-all-empty-lines):

   ```
   while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       String auxTrimmed = aux.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
       // more code
   }
   ```
2. If you experience this problem always, just ignore last line:

   ```
   String[] data = lastLineMinusOne.split(",");
   logger.info(lastLineMinusOne);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, using some good library is a best way, if you do it not for education. CSV looks simple, until you face text in quotes, escape characters, different line endings and so on.

In your case you can use apache commons.csv

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

and short usage example, note **withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)**:

```
final CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
                .withDelimiter(',');
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), format);
Iterator<CSVRecord> iterator = parser.iterator();
```