# Replace multiple line spacings with one line spacing?

Tags: java, string

How do I replace multiple line spacings with one line spacing in a string?

I want this:

```
Hello!







Hello again!
```

to be converted to this:

```
Hello!
Hello again!
```

or this:

```
Hello!

Hello again!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
str.replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
```

Here is an example :

```
String str = "Hello!\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "Hello again!";
str = str.replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output**

```
Hello!
Hello again!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Bart Kiers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123485/2361752) to remove empty lines within a string.

```
String removedEmptyLines = text.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Queue . 
Read line by line 
If first character of line is not a new line character , include it in the queue.
Otherwise  if its a space just peek last element is queue,  dont add it if the queue last element was also new line .

So when you print also , you have the liberty you want to print new line character or not .