# To remove newline space between lines in String using java

Tags: java, string

I need to remove space between string lines using java.Thanks in advance. **Note:** already tried some ways like `StringUtils.normalizeSpace(input)` , `input.replaceAll(" ","")`,`input.replaceAll("\\s","")`; which doesn't give correct result.

**Input:**

```
Status /Action

Query/Comment

Dealership Name:

Northern Region Hyundai Australia / Driveaway Quotation

Dealer Code:

 4219

Dealer Name:

VON BIBRA

Contact Name:

Mr Chris Justin
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Status /Action
Query/Comment
Dealership Name:
Northern Region Hyundai Australia / Driveaway Quotation
Dealer Code:
4219
Dealer Name:
VON BIBRA
Contact Name:
Mr Chris Justin
```

Comment: you'll be reading this from a file right?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123385/remove-all-empty-lines

Comment: Hi @JennisVaishnav
I am reading this content from emailbody. not from file.thanks for response. let me know if u found solution,

Comment: @RamachandraReddy didn't find this same as mentioned link. The link removes all the new lines from the code. There's a difference to note.

Comment: @Justin sure I'll help you.

Comment: Hi @RamachandraReddy
I'll try the solution which are available on that link and will let you know whether it satisfy my requirement or not. thanks