# How to replace double quotes with a newline character in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to spark. I have a huge file which has data like-

```
18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@00@31@2981546 " "18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@19@18@3240165 " "18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@18@18@1362836
13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@31@26@2880701 " "13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@19@18@1230206 " "13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@00@00@1631440
40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@79@18@1270246 " "40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@79@18@3276502 " "40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@19@07@3321860
```

I am trying to replace " " with new line character so that my output looks like this-

```
18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@00@31@2981546 
18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@19@18@3240165 
18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@18@18@1362836
13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@31@26@2880701 
13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@19@18@1230206 
13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@00@00@1631440
40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@79@18@1270246 
40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@79@18@3276502 
40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@19@07@3321860
```

I have tried with-

```
val fact1 =  sc.textFile("s3://abc.txt").map(x=>x.replaceAll("\"","\n"))
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Can someone tell what I am missing?

Edit1- My final output will be a dataframe with schema imposed after splitting with delimeter "@".

I am getting below o/p-

```
scala> fact1.take(5).foreach(println)
18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@00@31@2981546

18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@19@18@3240165

18765967790@18765967790@T@20130629@18@18@1362836
13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@31@26@2880701

13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@19@18@1230206

13478756094@13478756094@T@20130629@00@00@1631440
40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@79@18@1270246

40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@79@18@3276502

40072066693@40072066693@T@20130629@19@07@3321860
```

I am getting extra blank lines which is further troubling me to create dataframe. This might seem simple here, but the file is huge, also the rows containing " " are long. In the question I have put only 2 double quotes but they can be more than 40-50 in numbers.

Comment: What was your output?

Comment: Probably you wanted to replace it like so `x.replaceAll(" \" \"","\n")`

Comment: What you did is correct, what is your actual output?

Try below and see the difference:

`val file = spark.sparkContext.textFile("sc.textFile(\"s3://abc.txt\")")
file.foreach(print)

val fact1 = file.map(x=>x.replaceAll("\"","\n"))
fact1.foreach(print)
`

Comment: @Belwal I am getting some blank rows with that

Comment: I think it is because of multiple quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one quote in between textes, which is creating multiple line breaks. You either need to remove additional quotes before replace or empty lines after replace:

```
.map(x=>x.replaceAll("\"","\n").replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", ""))
```

Reference: [Remove all empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123385/remove-all-empty-lines)

Comment: But isn' t there any other way to replace all " " with newline or any other character in spark ?

Comment: Spark provides a way to transform(like map in this case) the data. Now what you want to transform is up to you. We are just manipulating the string which can be done in different ways too and spark has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing implicit Encoders and you try the code as below

```
spark.read.text("src/main/resources/doubleQuoteFile.txt").map(row => {
      row.getString(0).replace("\"","\n") // looking to replace " " with next line
      row.getString(0).replace("\" \"","\n") // looking to replace " " with next line
    })(org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.STRING)
```